# Glassfish cannot reference jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, svn, glassfish

I have eclipse Luna, glassfish 3.1 i work with JSF, in my company we work with the code repository SVN. My dynamic web project was working well until someone gave a commit in the project and now the i get an error of :

CANNOT DEPLOY THE PROJECT

After a check i get that there were a problem with tihis packages

import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import javax.mail.Address;

import javax.servlet

so i imported each jar for start working back again, but i know that this is a bad practise, so could someone say to me how i can keep this references with these jars avoiding to manually import them?

Where in glassfish i configure that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven to manage your jar dependencies. That way, manual imports are not needed.

Comment: I´m not the boss i can´t use maven i have to solve without it